# Can I link a K8s deployment to PVCs by label or selector instead of name?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a deployment in Kubernetes. In this deployment, I can specify a persistent volume claim as follows:

```
  volumes:
  - name: my-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: my-claim
```

I have a disk (an Azure disk to be precise) with lots of preprocessed data, which I can expose in Kubernetes as PVC with name `my-claim`. In the next step I link it to the deployment as shown above. The problem with this approach is, that I cannot scale the deployment to more than one pod.

How can I scale this setup? I tried to duplicate the disk and create it as second PVC with a different name. This worked, but now I don't see a way to tell the Kubernetes deployment, that each pod should mount one of these two PVCs.

I hope there is an option to mark both PVCs with a common label and then link my deployment to this label instead of the PVC name. Is something like this out there or is my approach completely wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution using two replicas of a StatefulSet - that should work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. It gave lots of insights about the underlying concepts. The reason to use Azure Disks are high performance requirements, which Azure Files can't match.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, I agree, Azure Disks is a better option - more cloud native. Also Utlra disk seem to be the most performant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-ultra-disks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a disk (an Azure disk to be precise) with lots of preprocessed data, which I can expose in Kubernetes as PVC with name my-claim. In the next step I link it to the deployment as shown above. The problem with this approach is, that I cannot scale the deployment to more than one pod.

Here, you use a `PersistentVolumeClaim` with [Access Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) `ReadWriteOnce` (that's the only option for Azure Disks, see access mode link)

> How can I scale this setup? I tried to duplicate the disk and create it as second PVC with a different name. This worked, but now I don't see a way to tell the Kubernetes deployment, that each pod should mount one of these two PVCs.

Here, it sounds like you want a volume with *access mode* `ReadOnlyMany` - so you need to consider a storage system that support this *access mode*.

> I tried to duplicate the disk and create it as second PVC with a different name. This worked, but now I don't see a way to tell the Kubernetes deployment, that each pod should mount one of these two PVCs.

This does not work for a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) because the `template` for each pod is identical. But you can do this with [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/), declaring your PVC with `volumeClaimTemplates` - then the PVC for each pod has in **unique, well known identity**.

Example part of `StatefulSet`:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: my-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Then if you have two replicas of you StatefulSet, they will you a PVC named `my-pvc-0` and `my-pvc-1` where the number is called "ordinal". The `volumeClaimTemplate` only creates a new PVC if it does not exists, so if you have created PVCs with the correct names - the existing will be used.

### Alternative Storage Solutions

An alternative storage solution to Azure Disk is Azure Files. Azure Files support *access mode* `ReadWriteOnce`, `ReadOnlyMany` and `ReadWriteMany`. See [Dynamically create and use a persistent volume with Azure Files in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv).

There may also be other storage alternatives that better fit your application.